# Define Batch process parameters

Tags: batch-file, windows-server

I define some parameter when calling a batch file:

```
:: Usertype:I,C
set Usertype=%~1
set Deltaval=%~2
If Usertype=="C" set Gender=NA
set Gender=%~3
If Gender==NA 
(
goto
END
)
```

However, I got issue at line *If Usertype=="C" set Gender = NA* with following error: 
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Are there any solution to it?

Comment: Actually, no, you have more issues than just that one. you forgot the `%` which defines that the words are variables. `if /I "%userType%"=="C"`  Also you need to explain what you are trying to do as `%usertype%` currently has a value `:~1` and `%dataval%` has a value of `~2` so not sure where you planned on using it. I suggest you read some help files. Open `cmd` and type `set /?` and `if /?` and lastly, the `goto` and `END` are on separate lines and I do not see `:END` label defined.

Comment: you can also not have a space when setting variables like `set Gender = NA` as that will create a variable with a space `%Gender %` and a value with a leading whitespace.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thanks. There are some errors while copying. I've updated code...

Comment: Ok. Did you look at my comments on how to use variables?

Comment: Yes. But What im trying to do is
Usertype is first parameter
Deltaval is second parameter
if Usertype is "C" then set Gender==NA. Otherwise, we must put Gender as third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I am trying to tell you, you need to use `%` in order to define the words you use as variables and not see them as plain text.

```
:: Usertype:I,C
set "Usertype=%~1"
set "Deltaval=%~2"
If /i "%Usertype%"=="C" If /i "%Usertype%"=="I" (
    set "Gender=NA"
    ) else (
    set "Gender=%~3"
   )
If "%Gender%"=="NA" goto :eof
```

Or you can do

```
:: Usertype:I,C
set "Usertype=%~1"
set "Deltaval=%~2"
If /i not "%Usertype%"=="C" If /i not "%Usertype%"=="I" do something
```

Comment: Txn. I've tried with new If-Else statement:
````:: Usertype:I,C
set Usertype=%~1
set Deltaval=%~2
If Usertype=="C" (set Gender=NA) else (set Gender=%~3)
If Gender==NA 
(
goto END
)````

Comment: Yup i see. But what is diferent betwween If /i and without /i

Comment: that is just matching case insensitively for `c` so would match both `c` and `C`, but that is not important here. The `%` wrap around the variable names is important here. Did you try it as is?

Comment: Thanks. It works fine now... But how can I define If %Usertype% NEQ (I,C) then do smt...